# Facing errors with running shell scripts at startup and poweroff

Tags: linux, shell, startup, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to run 3 scripts at startup. They are named as follows: `voe.sh` `startUp.sh` and `runDown.sh`

The script `voe.sh` is the main file which will in turn call the other 2 files, depending on if the system is booting up or shutting down respectively.

I copied all the 3 files to the directory `/etc/init.d`. I then used `sysv-rc-conf` utility, to add them to appropriate run levels as follows:

```
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sysv-rc-conf --list voe
voe          0:off  1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sysv-rc-conf --list startUp
startUp      0:off  1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sysv-rc-conf --list runDown
runDown      0:off  1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

I checked the all the `rc*.d` directories and all of them have correct symbolic links to `/etc/init.d` directory where all the 3 scripts have been kept. The permissions of these scripts also seem to be correct:

```
shankar@shannkardell:/etc/init.d$ ls -l voe startUp runDown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2781 Apr 20 14:58 runDown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2576 Apr 20 14:57 startUp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2242 Apr 20 14:57 voe
```

Even after all this, when I restart my machine, my `boot.log` says:

```
/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: /etc/rc2.d/S20voe: not found
```

Also, I tried to test the `voe.sh` from another directory (where I had also kept the other 2 in the same directory) by running it as follows:

```
shankar@shannkardell:~/Important Files$ sudo bash voe.sh start
Starting GT.M for shankarNow using node v4.2.6 (npm v2.14.12)
-su: startUp.sh: command not found
*
```

I am not an expert with Ubuntu. So if I could get any guidance on this issue, it would be great.

Thanks

**Edit**

Following is the ls -l on the 3 scripts I am concerned about:

```
shankar@shannkardell:/etc/init.d$ ls -l runDown voe startUp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2781 Apr 20 14:58 runDown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2242 Apr 20 14:57 voe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2576 Apr 20 14:57 startUp

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc0.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 13 21:24 K80runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 13 21:24 K80startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 K80voe -> ../init.d/voe

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc1.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 13 21:24 K80runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 13 21:24 K80startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 K80voe -> ../init.d/voe

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc2.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 S20voe -> ../init.d/voe

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc3.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 S20voe -> ../init.d/voe

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc4.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 S20voe -> ../init.d/voe

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc5.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 20 15:28 S20startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 S20voe -> ../init.d/voe

shankar@shannkardell:/etc/rc6.d$ ls -l *runDown *startUp *voe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 13 21:24 K80runDown -> ../init.d/runDown
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 13 21:24 K80startUp -> ../init.d/startUp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 20 18:58 K80voe -> ../init.d/voe
```

`voe.sh` script (Residing at /etc/init.d/voe):

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# $Source: /home/fwslc/lsb-fwslc/inst.bin/RCS/voe,v $
# $Revision: 20100820.1 $
#
# chkconfig: 2345 15 85
# description: GT.M System Startup and Shutdown scripts
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          wvehrvoe10
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Sequence Managers startup/rundown scripts
# Description:       System Startup and Shutdown scripts
### END INIT INFO

# Author: K.S. Bhaskar <bhaskar@worldvista.org>
# Tweaked by Gus Landis <ldl@linux.com>
# Tweaked further by David Wicksell <dlw@linux.com>

# Do NOT "set -e"

# Source function library
bash -xv
source /lib/lsb/init-functions

NAME="`basename $0 | sed 's/...//'`"
PATH=/home/shankar/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESC="GT.M start/rundown scripts"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

#
# Function that starts WorldVistA EHR VOE/2.0oe
#
do_start() {
  echo -n Starting GT.M for ${NAME} 
  echo `date` - Starting GT.M for ${NAME} >> /var/log/boot.log
  su - ${NAME} -c /home/shankar/bin/startUp.sh
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    log_success_msg
    echo GT.M for ${NAME} started successfully >> /var/log/boot.log
    touch /var/lock/${NAME}
  else
    log_failure_msg
    echo GT.M for ${NAME} did not start successfully >> /var/log/boot.log
  fi
  echo
}

#
# Function that stops WorldVistA EHR VOE/2.0oe
#
do_stop() {
  echo -n Stopping GT.M for ${NAME} 
  echo `date` - Stopping GT.M for ${NAME} >> /var/log/boot.log
  su - ${NAME} -c /home/shankar/runDown.sh
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    log_success_msg
    rm /var/lock/${NAME}
    echo GT.M for ${NAME} stopped successfully >> /var/log/boot.log
  else
    log_failure_msg
    echo GT.M for ${NAME} did not stop successfully >> /var/log/boot.log
  fi
  echo
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    do_start
    ;;
  stop)
    do_stop
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    do_stop
    do_start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    echo "Not expected to run from /etc/init.d, but rather from /etc/rc?.d"
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

# $RCSfile: voe,v $
```

`startUp.sh` script (Residing at /home/shankar/bin/startUp.sh):

```
#! /bin/bash -l
#
# Package:       FWSLC Infrastructure
# File:          gtm_start.sh
# Summary:       init script to start GT.M
# Maintainer:    LD Landis & DL Wicksell
# Last Modified: Aug 20, 2010
#
# Written by LD Landis <ldl@linux.com>
#          & DL Wicksell <dlw@linux.com>
# Copyright © 2010 Fourth Watch Software, LC
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License (AGPL)
# as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
# the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
# GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
# along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
#
# $Source: /home/fwslc/lsb-fwslc/inst.bin/RCS/gtm_start.sh,v $
# $Revision: 20100820.1 $
#
# Ensures that GT.M is recovered and starts new journal
bash -xv
cd /home/shankar
source /home/shankar/EHR/env2

LOGDIR=/home/shankar/log/`basename $0 .sh`
LOG=${LOGDIR}/`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`

if [ ! -d ${LOGDIR} ] ; then
  mkdir -p ${LOGDIR}
fi

if [ ! -r /home/shankar/EHR/g/mumps.mjl ] ; then
  echo "No database to start in `pwd`"                         > ${LOG}
  exit 1
fi

echo "**Recover Journals**"                                   >> ${LOG}
mupip journal -recover -backward /home/shankar/EHR/g/mumps.mjl              >> ${LOG} 2>&1
#mupip journal -recover -backward ~/EHR/j/ewdgbl.mjl               >> ${LOG} 2>&1
echo "**Enable Journals**"                                    >> ${LOG}
mupip set -journal="enable,on,before" -file /home/shankar/EHR/g/mumps.dat   >> ${LOG} 2>&1
#mupip set -journal="enable,on,before" -file ~/EHR/g/ewdgbl.dat    >> ${LOG} 2>&1
echo "**Rundown database**"                                   >> ${LOG}
mupip rundown -reg "*"                                        >> ${LOG} 2>&1
if [ "${REPL_SIDE}" == "PRIMARY" ] ; then
  echo "**Starting Taskman**"                                 >> ${LOG}
  echo y | mumps -run START^ZTMB                              >> ${LOG} 2>&1
  if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
    echo "###Successfully finished###"                        >> ${LOG}
  else
    echo "###Did not run successfully###"                     >> ${LOG}
  fi
fi

exit 0

# $RCSfile: gtm_start.sh,v $
```

`runDown.sh` script (Residing at /home/shankar/bin/runDown.sh):

```
#! /bin/bash -l
#
# Package:       FWSLC Infrastructure
# File:          gtm_rundown.sh
# Summary:       init script to stop GT.M
# Maintainer:    LD Landis & DL Wicksell
# Last Modified: Jan 24, 2012
#
# Written by LD Landis <ldl@linux.com>
#          & DL Wicksell <dlw@linux.com>
# Copyright © 2010-2012 Fourth Watch Software, LC
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License (AGPL)
# as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
# the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
# GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
# along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
#
# $Source: /home/fwslc/lsb-fwslc/inst.bin/RCS/gtm_rundown,sh,v $
# $Revision: 20121217.1 $
#
# Stop GT.M
bash -xv
cd /home/shankar
source /home/shankar/EHR/env2

LOGDIR=/home/shankar/log/`basename $0 .sh`
LOG=${LOGDIR}/`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`

if [ ! -d ${LOGDIR} ] ; then
  mkdir -p ${LOGDIR}
fi

if [ ! -r /home/shankar/EHR/g/mumps.dat ] ; then
  echo "No db to rundown in `pwd`"                           > ${LOG}
  exit 1
fi

if [ "${REPL_SIDE}" == "PRIMARY" ] ; then
  (
  mumps -direct << EOF
s U="^"
d STOP^ZTMKU
y
y
y
h
EOF
  )                                                             >> ${LOG} 2>&1

  TEST="true" STIME=`date '+%s'`
  while ${TEST}
    do
      gtm_prompt="" TEST=`mumps -direct <<< 'w $d(^%ZTSCH("RUN"))#2'`

      if [ ${TEST} -eq 1 ] ; then
        TEST="true"
      elif [ ${TEST} -eq 0 ] ; then
        TEST="false"
      else
        echo "`basename $0` may have a bug in it"               >> ${LOG} 2>&1
      fi

      NOW=`date '+%s'`

      if [ `expr ${NOW} - ${STIME}` -ge 30 ] ; then
        TEST="false"

        echo "TaskMan took too long to shut down, force quit"   >> ${LOG} 2>&1
        echo
      fi
    done
fi

CMD="pgrep -u ${USER} mumps"

PROCS=`eval ${CMD}`
if [ ! -z "${PROCS}" ] ; then
  for i in `echo ${PROCS}`
  do
    mupip stop ${i}                                             >> ${LOG} 2>&1
  done                                                          
fi

sleep 1

PROCS=`eval ${CMD}`
if [ ! -z "${PROCS}" ] ; then
  pkill -9 mumps                                                >> ${LOG} 2>&1
fi

sleep 1

mupip rundown -region "*"                                       >> ${LOG} 2>&1

exit 0

# $RCSfile: gtm_rundown.sh,v $
```

Answer (score 0):

I see name mismatch. There is `voe` inside `/etc/init.d` and you try to call `voe.sh`. Please check the names

Comment: With `sudo bash voe.sh start`, I am only trying to check if the script is running fine or not. I am executing it from a personal directory `~\Important  Files`. That's why I called it using `voe.sh`

Comment: Please show your `ls -l /etc/rc2.d/S20voe` and all the relevant file(s) and link(s). I think there is a mismatch either in the file(s) placement or in the PATH contents. By the way, are you sure that root's PATH is good enough for running your scripts?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I have added the outputs as you asked for. Kindly let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks

Comment: Does the voe script try to run the command "su startUp.sh"? Please also share the content of voe if possible?

Comment: Hi @StianSkjelstad, I added the 3 scripts.

Comment: @Ohm I still do not see the contents of `voe`. One more thing. Please add to all your scripts the `-xv` to the `bash` invocation. It should be `bash -xv`. The log should then say what happens exactly.

Comment: @Michael The contents of voe are in the voe.sh script. Let me know if its not visible?

Comment: @Michael, as you suggested, I added `bash -xv` to all the 3 scripts. But, in boot.log, I do not see more information than what I was getting earlier. It gives only one error still: `/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: /etc/rc2.d/S20voe: not found`

Comment: I do see debug output when I run your scripts. Please look for the lines starting with '+' symbol. Something like `++ '[' '\s-\v\$ ' ']'`

Comment: @Michael, I am sorry I didn't understand you Michael. Should I run the scripts locally (like `bash startUp.sh`)? Only then I will be able to see debugging lines (like one you mentioned)?

Comment: You can run them locally. You can also manually add logging to the scrips or find the place on disk where the logs are written (they exist for sure). It does not matter. You just have to see the full log of the run. It should contain the exact reason of the failure

Answer (score 0):

Just to learn a couple of details:
Executing `runStart` `runStart.sh` are two different commands. In Windows, the fileending .exe .com .bat etc are not needed, in unix you need to write the full filename always.

Next problem, `voe` executes `runStart` and `runStop`, in other words, `runStart` and `runStop` should not be in the `/etc/rc.d` directory and friends, only `voe`. Move them to a known file-location. For instance `/home/shankar/bin/runStart.sh`. You are then going to need to use a full-path when you are going to execute these two helpers, since their path is not in the `$PATH` environment list (this also goes if the file is in the local directory, then you would need to first `cd /home/shanker/bin` before executing like this `./runStart.sh`, to make sure you are in the correct directory, and execute from there.

Comment: as per your suggestions, I moved `startUp.sh` and `runDown.sh` to `/home/shankar/bin`. I removed their corresponding links in rc0.d and other friend directories. Now, only `voe` (not as `voe.sh`) exists in `init.d` directory. In script for `voe`, I provided full path to `startUp.sh` and `runDown.sh` directory. However, I am still getting the same error: `/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: /etc/rc2.d/S20voe: not found`. I have updated all the scripts above. You can refer them for your reference.

Comment: There are some dead links inside /etc/rc2.d and friends. Update the voe ones, and delete the runStart and runStop ones

Comment: I removed all links of `voe` in `rc2.d` directory and friends. I also added the service again using `update-rc.d`. The output of `sysv-rc-conf` also shows me `voe` in different format levels. But `boot.log` only says `/etc/init.d/rc: 121: /etc/init.d/rc: /etc/rc2.d/S20voe: not found`. As `rc2.d` as current directoy, I also checked if `S20voe` exists or not by `ls -l`. It does indeed exist with a very light green light.

Comment: Can you pastebin your version of /etc/init.d/rc , I want to see what it does on line 121 (and the lines before that)

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand. Can you tell me about pastebin?